# Python, Pandas aggregate rows when the B value does not change. Take sum of C values and first A value. Keep the B value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['14:45:18', '14:45:02', '14:30:04', '14:30:00', '14:29:54', '14:29:34'],
'B': [891.1, 891.1, 891.8, 891.1, 891.1, 891.2],
'C': [3317, 1, 10, 2, 32, 33]})
```

output:

```
          A      B     C
0  14:45:18  891.1  3317 # <-- these two rows should be combined
1  14:45:02  891.1     1 # <-- these two rows should be combined
2  14:30:04  891.8    10
3  14:30:00  891.1     2 # <-- also these two rows should be combined
4  14:29:54  891.1    32 # <-- also these two rows should be combined
5  14:29:34  891.2    33
```

How can I make it like this:

```
          A      B     C
0  14:45:18  891.1  3318
1  14:30:04  891.8    10
2  14:30:00  891.1    34
3  14:29:34  891.2    33
```

In summary, how can I compare each line B value and...

- if they have same B value then sum their C values
- also, keep the first same A value

Comment: How come you've still got more than one B == 891.1? Is that deliberate or a posting mistake? Surely that should occur once with an A of 14:45:18 and a C of 3352?

Comment: @JonClements it comes from the raw data. At time14:45:18 and 14:45:02, have 2 command to purchase at price 891.1 with volume at 3317 and 1

Comment: Ahh... so immediately consecutive lines... so what'd happen where there were 3 or more consecutive B's... eg... the entire input was just all 891.1... how'd that end up in the output?

Comment: @JonClements Let me explain. If the price at 14:00:00 was 890 and 14:00:01 was 891.1, it means there are some buying commands. But if at 14:00:00 was 892 and 14:00:01 still was 891.1, it means there are some selling commands. That is why I dont want to group all same B values.

Comment: @JonClements if all next lines were 891.1 then group all volume with the first 891.1.

Comment: The term for this would be *"aggregate rows when the B value does not change. Take sum of C values and first A value. Keep the B value"*

Comment: @smci Sorry for asking stupid question. Should I change the title like your suggestion. I'm new to stackoverflow. Will your title make others easier to search when they have same problem.

Comment: StanSal: welcome to SO! It's up to you, it's fine to leave it as is. For frequently-asked topics like this, it's good to have titles with a variety of phrasings, so that people find them via search (StackOverflow internal search, or Google).

Comment: Note: this is not just a simple `df.groupby('B')...` as I first thought, because you don't want all the B == 891.1 values in one group, you want a different group each time B changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
groups = df.B.ne(df.B.shift()).cumsum()
aggregated_df = df.groupby(groups,as_index=False).agg({'A':'first','B':'first','C':'sum'})
print(aggregated_df)

          A      B     C
0  14:45:18  891.1  3318
1  14:30:04  891.8    10
2  14:30:00  891.1    34
3  14:29:34  891.2    33
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I spend all day long to write in for loop with if condition. And now you just solve it with so simple and beautiful code.